# flutter NFC Management packagae

Tags: android, flutter

hey i'm usungi the pacakage nfc_manager  for flutter https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager .
when i try to launch the app I receive the following error :

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':nfc_manager:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
     Required by:
         project :nfc_manager > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
         project :nfc_manager > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0
         project :nfc_manager > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0
      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
               > Operation timed out (Read failed)
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':nfc_manager' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':nfc_manager' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

If someone can help me ?

Comment: have you tried to update ur graddle ?

Comment: yes that no help me